# How to fix Entity Framework Core "Argument types do not match" with Linq Select projection

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When attempting a straight forward projection using Entity Framework Core and Linq, I am getting an "Argument types do not match" exception.

I have looked into possible causes and have narrowed it down to the `Select` that is causing the error (see below). There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5522) describing a similar situation with simple types and optional navigation entities, but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. It is not a `nullable` type and I have tried casting or using `Value` on any child properties. I have also tried setting the relationship to required in the `DbContext` which isn't exactly ideal.

Here is the Linq query in the repository:

```
return await _dashboardContext.PresetDashboardConfig
    .Where(config => config.DashboardTypeId == dashboardType && config.OrganisationType = organisationType)
    .GroupBy(config => config.GroupId)
    .Select(config => new DashboardConfigDTO
    {
        DashboardType = config.First().DashboardTypeId,
        OrganisationId = organisationId,
        WidgetGroups = config.Select(group => new WidgetGroupDTO
        {
            Id = group.Id,
            Name = group.GroupName,
            TabOrder = group.TabOrder,

            // Problem Select below:
            Widgets = group.Widgets.Select(widget => new WidgetConfigDTO
            {
                IndicatorId = widget.IndicatorId,
                ScopeId = widget.ScopeId.ToString(),
                ParentScopeId = widget.ParentScopeId.ToString(),
                WidgetType = widget.WidgetType,
                WidgetSize = widget.WidgetSize,
                Order = widget.Order
            })
        })
    })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

And the entities:

```
public class DashboardConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DashboardTypeId { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationType {get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int TabOrder { get; set; }
}

public class PresetDashboardConfig : DashboardConfig
{
    public ICollection<PresetWidgetConfig> Widgets { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IndicatorId { get; set; }
    public long ScopeId { get; set; }
    public long? ParentScopeId { get; set; }
    public int WidgetType { get; set; }
    public int WidgetSize { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class PresetWidgetConfig : WidgetConfig
{
    public int PresetDashboardConfigId { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the DbContext ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PresetDashboardConfig>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.GroupName)
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    entity.HasMany(e => e.Widgets)
        .WithOne();
});
```

Below are the DTO classes as per Henk's comment:

```
public class DashboardConfigDTO
{
    public int DashboardType { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WidgetGroupDTO> WidgetGroups { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetGroupDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TabOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WidgetConfigDTO> Widgets { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetConfigDTO
{
    public int IndicatorId { get; set; }
    public string ScopeId { get; set; }
    public string ParentScopeId { get; set; }
    public int WidgetType { get; set; }
    public int WidgetSize { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework Core version `2.1.8` and ASP.NET Core version `2.1.1`

Comment: I have edited the entities to closer match what I have in my project (inheritance).

Comment: Unfortunately I have no such environment. You could try and see if it reproduces in the latest EF Core 2.2

Comment: Can you post the DashboardConfigDTO class? Plenty what could go wrong there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - DTOs added to the question if it helps